# Devices disconnect from CWM when trying to sideload

Tags: side-loading

```
c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb devices
List of devices attached
F5AZFG27S553    device


c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb sideload UL-Z00A-WW-2.20.40.165-user.zip
loading: 'UL-Z00A-WW-2.20.40.165-user.zip'
error: device '(null)' not found

c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb devices
List of devices attached
```

I will try again and see if devices are there when I select sideload from cwm

I did it again.

```
Now the message is error: closed

**c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb devices
List of devices attached
F5AZFG27S553    device


c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb sideload UL-Z00A-WW-2.20.40.165-user.zip
loading: 'UL-Z00A-WW-2.20.40.165-user.zip'
error: closed

c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb devices
List of devices attached
F5AZFG27S553    device


c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb devices
List of devices attached
F5AZFG27S553    device


c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb sideload UL-Z00A-WW-2.20.40.165-user.zip
loading: 'UL-Z00A-WW-2.20.40.165-user.zip'
error: closed

c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb devices
List of devices attached
F5AZFG27S553    device


c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb sideload UL-Z00A-WW-2.20.40.165-user.zip
loading: 'UL-Z00A-WW-2.20.40.165-user.zip'
error: closed

c:\Users\jim2\Downloads>adb devices
List of devices attached
F5AZFG27S553    device
```

Comment: Error Closed the majority of the time is because adb.exe is out of date.

Comment: In which case, an up-to-date set can be found [in the download area of my site](https://android.izzysoft.de/downloads) (minimal package: adb, fastboot, aapt – suitable for the average user without having tons of unnecessary stuff attached ;) for Linux, Mac and Windows.